# My Html canvas is null. Really annoying

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

i used a udemy course to make a simple pong game.
I am now recreating it again as practice and i keep getting the error canvas is null. Any Help?

```
<html>
 <canvas id="gamecanvas" width="600" height="800"></canvas>
<script>
var canvas = null;
var Context = null;

window.onload = function(){

canvas.document.getElementById("gamecanvas");
Context.canvas.getContext("2d");
 drawEverything();
 }

function drawEverything() {
Context.fillStyle = "black";
Context.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

Context.fillStyle  = "white";
Context.fillRect(0,360,20,80);


Context.fillStyle  = "white";
Context.fillRect(580,360,20,80);


Context.fillStyle = "green";
context.beginpath();
context.arc(0,0,10,10,Math.PI*2,true);
context.fill();


}
```

Comment: Maybe `canvas = document.getElementById("gamecanvas")` over on the `onload` function?

Comment: You're doing `canvas.document`, so basically trying to access the property `document` of a `null` object

Comment: You'll also encounter problems because `context != Context`.

Comment: `beginpath !== beginPath`

Answer (score 1):

That is because you set it to null! Change

```
canvas.document.getElementById("gamecanvas");
```

To

```
canvas = document.getElementById("gamecanvas");
```

Otherwise, you never set canvas.

Comment: That's not the only problem. JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this.

```
canvas = document.getElementById("gamecanvas");
Context = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

Answer (score 0):

You set canvas to null so of course it will be null. This should help.

```
canvas = document.getElementById("gamecanvas")
context = canvas.getContext("2d");
```